# Opencart With Codeigniter getting 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, opencart

Im using codeignitier as framework and want to install opencart, SO i used a sub folder in Public_html and called it store !

Now when i load in im getting a 404 error any ideas??

so public_html looks like:

```
application
assets
cgi-bin
store
system
uploads
.htaccess
index.php
php.ini
welcome.html
```

Thanks

Comment: It could be the `.htaccess` - depending on how it's set up?

Answer (score 0):

in your `store` sub-directory, in the file **.htaccess** (not .htaccess.txt)

find `RewriteBase /` and replace it to `RewriteBase /store/`

This can be one reason other reason can be in your codeignitor's .htaccess file